# Unable to create a view of type solr search

Tags: views, 6, search

I have installed the apachesolr , views and apachesolr_views modules but I am unable to create a view of type solr search.
Is there something i am missing? Because the apachesolr_views provides views integration of apachesolr.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Install the modules that you have mentioned
2. Install and configure Apache Solr in your server
3. Configure Apache Solr server in the apachesolr module settings
4. Add a view. Select Apache Solr localhost server (or the name that you have given to your Apache Solr server configuration in apachesolr settings) in the Show dropdown menu when creating the view.

Steps for installing and configuring Solr:

1. Download the .zip file from http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ (you might want to try with version 3, although it has worked for me with 4
2. Unzip in a folder in your machine
3. Copy all the contents from sites/all/modules/apachesolr/solr-config/solr-3.x/ to apache-solr/example/solr/conf/ in the folder you created in step 2
4. Start the server with running java -jar start.jar

Check in the admin section of your Drupal site if the server is found and working.

Comment: I did not configure the server for apache solr. therefore I am unable to create the view of type apache solr?

Comment: That's probably the issue, the apachesolr_views module needs a configured solr instance in order to create a view. Do you know how to install and configure solr?

Comment: No, how will i configure it on local?

Comment: I have added installation steps in the answer above.

Comment: I have isntalled the apachesolr on my local and created a search environment in the apache solr settings but still I am unable to to add a view of type solr search.